# Iframe not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on safari browser to include an iframe content, the code is like this:

```
 <iframe src="http://internal001.zizsoft.com/test/lookbook/test.html" style="height:800px;" />
```

The problem is the inside content is not scale or show correctly ,

if I try the other way to load the page . eg. jquery.load("html") function the content inside is not clickable/ scrollable

I have include some fixing code search on the internet but no luck.

```
$(function(){
    if (/iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent))
        $('iframe').wrap(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            return $('<div />').css({
                width: $this.attr('width'),
                height: $this.attr('height'),
                overflow: 'auto',
                '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'
            });
        });
});
```

Here is the demo site:

http://internal001.zizsoft.com/test/lookbook/test.html

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why don't you just stop using iframes? In 2015, I see no sense in using iframes except for sandboxing.

Comment: sure , any other way to include the page

http://internal001.zizsoft.com/test/lookbook/index.html in http://internal001.zizsoft.com/test/lookbook/test.html

thanks

Comment: Just include it, as an HTML.